# TTSpeechBubbleShape in Three20 only draws "speech" triangles top and bottom

Tags: iphone, geometry, three20

So I am using the Three20 library for an iPhone app, and want to use the TTSpeechBubbleShape style for a view. But the triangle doesn't seem to want to draw on the left or right sides. I see in the source that it's a lot of geometry and was wondering if anyone had tackled this or knew how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `TTRoundedLeftArrowShape` and `TTRoundedRightArrowShape`, which would look like a standard Back iPhone button.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source and filled in the missing logic to draw the edge for the left and right side of the speech bubble.

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/buddydvd/three20/blob/861d57f9f46e9148dc8b85d25b1b5c4a215ae905/src/Three20Style/Sources/TTSpeechBubbleShape.m).

Changes to **addRightEdge**:

```
if (_pointLocation > 135 && _pointLocation < 225) {
  CGFloat pw = _pointAngle >= 90 && _pointAngle < 270 ? _pointSize.width : -_pointSize.width;
  CGFloat pointY = ((_pointLocation-135)/90)*fh;
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, fw, pointY-floor(_pointSize.height/2));
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, fw+pw, pointY);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, fw, pointY+floor(_pointSize.height/2));
}
```

Changes to **addLeftEdge**:

```
if ((_pointLocation > 315 && _pointLocation <= 360)
    || (_pointLocation >= 0 && _pointLocation < 45)) {
  CGFloat pw = ((_pointAngle >= 270 && _pointAngle <= 360)
                || (_pointAngle >= 0 && _pointAngle <= 90))
    ? _pointSize.width
    : -_pointSize.width;
  CGFloat pointY = (_pointLocation > 315 && _pointLocation <= 360)
    ? fh-(((_pointLocation-315)/90)*fh)
    : (fh/2)-((_pointLocation/90)*fh);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, pointY+floor(_pointSize.height/2));
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -pw, pointY);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, pointY-floor(_pointSize.height/2));
}
```

Comment: The asker should mark this answer as correct. Beautiful and simple to drop in. I'm using Three20 1.0.5 (the latest to date), and this code is missing form it, although I hope you submitted a pull request. Cheers! And thanks for the fix!