# Three20: the parameters of shapeWithRadius:pointLocation:pointAngle:pointSize in class TTSpeechBubbleShape

Tags: function, parameters, three20

Does anyone know the parameters of function shapeWithRadius:pointLocation:pointAngle:pointSize in the class TTSpeechBubbleShape? I want to design a dialog in which the arrow heads left. I tried some parameters but failed. The class TTRoundedLeftArrowShape can let arrow head left. But the arrow in it is located in the middle of left edge. I want to locate the arrow myself. How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

take a look

[TTSpeechBubbleShape in Three20 only draws "speech" triangles top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564583/ttspeechbubbleshape-in-three20-only-draws-speech-triangles-top-and-bottom)